# Getting OTRS to work with XAMPP

Tags: lamp, rhel5, xampp, otrs

Setting up a testing environment on a RHEL5 server to test out OTRS ticketing system.  I installed XAMPP for the ease of use factor for testing but can't seem to get the ticketing system to start with XAMPP at all.

I am new to OTRS and learning on the fly.  The documentation says to go to localhost/otrs/installer.pl.  First, this file does not exist anywhere in the directory except in /opt/otrs/cgi-bin & fcgi-bin. And when I attempted to start OTRS in general I get

"  --> Please start the web server first! (service httpd start) <--"

So do I need to edit the startup script to force it to use XAMPP? Or am I better off just installing HTTPD & MySQL myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OTRS start script assumes you have a web server with a process called 'httpd' if you're on RHEL. You do not use this because you chose XAMPP. So one solution would be to get around this by not using the OTRS start scripts;

my strong recommendation would be to not use XAMPP but go with the default MySQL and Apache provided by RHEL instead; this way you can simply RTFM for the OTRS installation and it will work. the XAMPP installation is absolutely *not* the easy way here!

Comment: Thanks Mike, you are right OTRS assumes a lot in its scripts which if your system deviates from the install goes terribly wrong.  Your recommendation of installing MySQL & Apache was much easier.